# Display nodes with same CCK radio button value in a Views block

Tags: 7, views

I have a CCK field with some values that you can choose with a radio button. When you are viewing a page that has one of the values selected, I'd like to show all of the other pages that have the same value selected in that field.

I have tried with contextual filters (adding that field as an argument), but nothing showed up.

How can this be achieved?

Thank you in advance for any help!